# Where to store files for admin to download in Django?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have some example files that I want to serve in a download link to all admins. They are not model dependant or user dependant (other than requiring admin). They're txt files and the same files must be available to all admins. I cannot find anything about this in the docs, or maybe I don't know what to look for. As far as I understand only css, js and images are static files, so should txt files be in /media/?

Where can I put these files so only admins can download them? Right now I have a hard coded link in my custom admin template to /media/admin/examples/data_template.txt, but anyone can get to this link. I have these configs in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Edit: I have also tried putting it in the admin static directory so I load it into the template with {% load static %} and href="{% static 'admin/example_files/data_template.txt' %}" - but I can still use the download link when logged out. I'm in development, obviously. Is it supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1):

so static files are those files that are usually part of your code, or part of your dependencies’ code. They could be javascript and CSS files, images for your web pages, etc.

Media files however are usually files that are uploaded by users or generated by your application during the life of your Django project. They are typically not stored in source control (like static files are). Basically, anything which is going into a FileField, ImageField is classified as media storage.

In your case, you can create a model with a file field and then add all the text files to that model. That will store these files in the media root. Then you can create a view wherein you check if the user is an admin or not, if yes then they can view, download those files.

Comment: But these files are not uploaded by a user. And I do want them stored in source control since they are a part of the website. As I understand I can do that by adding the files to git, having them in media and referring to them from an admin view. But right now if I log out from admin and copy-paste the url, I still get the file. Is that because I'm in development mode?

Comment: can u share the code please. If you want to give the files certain permissions you can add django mixins like loginrequiredmixin and permissionrequiredmixin to control who has access.